# AREL: writing complex update statements with from clause

Tags: postgresql, activerecord, sql-update, arel

I tried looking for an example of using `Arel::UpdateManager` to form an update statement with a from clause (as in `UPDATE t SET t.itty = "b" FROM .... WHERE ...`), couldn.t find any. The way I've seen it, `Arel::UpdateManager` sets the main engine on initialization and allows to set the various fields and values to update. Is there actually a way to do this?

Another aside would be to find out how to express Postgres posix regex matching into ARel, but this might be impossible by now.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I see the current version of `arel` gem is not support *FROM* keyword for the [sql](/questions/tagged/sql) query. You can generate a query using the *SET*, and *WHERE* keywords only, like:

```
UPDATE t SET t.itty = "b" WHERE ...
```

and the code, which copies a value from `field2` to `field1` for the `units` table, will be like:

```
relation = Unit.all
um = Arel::UpdateManager.new(relation.engine)
um.table(relation.table)
um.ast.wheres = relation.wheres.to_a
um.set(Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral.new('field1 = "field2"'))
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(um.to_sql)
```

Exactly you can use the additional method to update a relation. So we create the Arel's `UpdateManager`, assigning to it the table, `where` clause, and values to set. Values shell be passed to the method as an argument. Then we need to add `FROM` keyword to the generated `SQL` request, we add it only if we have access to external table of the specified one by the `UPDATE` clause itself. And at the last we executes the query. So we get:

```
def update_relation!(relation, values)
   um = Arel::UpdateManager.new(relation.engine)
   um.table(relation.table)
   um.ast.wheres = relation.wheres.to_a
   um.set(values)
   sql = um.to_sql

   # appends FROM field to the query if needed
   m = sql.match(/WHERE/)
   tables = relation.arel.source.to_a.select {|v| v.class == Arel::Table }.map(&:name).uniq
   tables.shift
   sql.insert(m.begin(0), "FROM #{tables.join(",")} ") if m && !tables.empty?

   # executes the query
   ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
 end
```

The you can issue the the relation update as:

```
values = Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral.new('field1 = "field2", field2 = NULL')
relation = Unit.not_rejected.where(Unit.arel_table[:field2].not_eq(nil))
update_relation!(relation, values)
```

Comment: Excellent, underrated answer! Pretty clean for a workaround! Someone should really submit a PR that adds `.from` support to `Arel::UpdateManager` and `update_all` though.

Comment: Do you have an example of a relation where you have used this where `relation.arel.source` contains more than 1 table? In my case, that only contained a single table, because the other tables are referenced in my subselect (`User.where( User[:id].in(Event.arel_table.project(Event[:user_id]) )
).arel.source.to_sql` => "users"), and it didn't automatically detect those. Would it be practical to also extract a list of tables referenced by the where clause (`arel.where_sql`/`arel.@ctx.wheres`)? Possible, but may require recursion. It might be helpful, then, to allow passing in list of tables?

Answer (score 0):

Building on Малъ Скрылевъ's answer, here's what I came up with, which lets you write it very similarly to the existing `relation.update_all` (which doesn't support `from`):

```rb
relation.update_all_from('something = other_table.something', from: 'other_table')
```

Here's the source:

```
class ActiveRecord::Relation
  # If you try to use update_all to do an SQL update that requires a "from" clause, you will end up getting:
  #   PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "table_name"
  # This variation lets you add the needed "from" clause.
  #
  # Usage:
  #   relation.update_all_from('something = other_table.something', from: 'other_table')
  #
  # This is a cross between update_all from activerecord gem and
  # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22501829/arel-writing-complex-update-statements-with-from-clause/23967126#23967126
  #
  def update_all_from(updates, from: nil)
    stmt = Arel::UpdateManager.new

    stmt.set Arel.sql(@klass.sanitize_sql_for_assignment(updates))
    stmt.table(table)

    if has_join_values? || offset_value
      @klass.connection.join_to_update(stmt, arel, arel_attribute(primary_key))
    else
      stmt.key = arel_attribute(primary_key)
      stmt.take(arel.limit)
      stmt.order(*arel.orders)
      stmt.wheres = arel.constraints
    end

    # Appends from clause to the query if needed
    sql = stmt.to_sql
    m = sql.match(/WHERE/)
    if from
      from = Array(from)
    else
      from = arel.source.to_a.select {|v| v.class == Arel::Table }.map(&:name).uniq[1..-1]
    end
    if m && !from.empty?
      sql.insert(m.begin(0), "FROM #{from.join(",")} ")
    end

    @klass.connection.update sql, "#{@klass} Update All"
  end
end
```